# Issue in iot edge hub + azure stream analytics

Tags: azure

We are trying to explore Azure Stream Analytics in IoT Edge. We are following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-stream-analytics) tutorial.

We have done following steps:

1. Created one Windows VM
2. Created one Edge device
3. Created on Azure Stream Analytics module, configured Input, Output and Query
4. Added a simulated temperature humidity sensor Sensor from Azure
   Market Place
5. Added Azure Stream Analytic module
6. Configure routes as mentioned in the tutorial and deployed in the Edge device
   (Azure VM)

By using commands I can see the 4 items in the device (Windows VM). Simulated sensor is sending data, but query is not triggered written in the ASA job. While checking the logs of edgeHub we found below error:

> TLS handshake failed., System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint, Byte[] clientHello) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__50_2(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint, Byte[] clientHello) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__50_2(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)<--- , 1b20a2d4

We created OpenSSL certificates in the VM and configured in the config.yaml, then it was giving error while checking the logs of the ASA mobule or Simulated Sensor module.